# A way to identify a unique number '$a_1$' has performed operations on '$x$'

Tags: mathematica

The problem I have is bit vague, so I will try to explain as best as I can.

Suppose we have a base number '$x$' and a set of unique number $'a_1', 'a_2', 'a_3', 'a_4'$ and so on

Now $a_1$ perform some operation on $x$ and results in $y_1$
From $y_1$, I should be able to identify that $a_1$ has performed operations on this number

Now on $y_1, a_2$ performed similar operations and results in $y_2$.
From $y_2$, I should be able to infer that either $a_1$ or $a_2$ has performed operations on it and none other numbers had ($a_3, a_4$ etc)

So I am looking for some logic, that can help me create this scenario.

Comment: Do you get to pick the numbers $x$, $a_1$, $a_2$, and so on, or are they all given to you and you only get to choose the operation?

Comment: What operations are permitted?  Assuming you are using $a_1$, can you form all of $a_1+x, a_1-x, x-a_1, x\cdot a_1, x/a_1, a_1/x$?  Any others?

Comment: I can pick x. a1, a2 etc are provided. We can do some transformation on a1, a2 as well like converting them to complex numbers if needed.

Comment: Any operations can be done. division, multiplication, complex, hashcode anything as long as the result again leads to a unique number.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the numbers $a_i$ are to be natural numbers, then a simple approach is to define the operation $\otimes:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that $a \otimes b=a p(a)^{b}$, where $p(a)$ is the smallest prime that does not divide $a$.  Starting with $x=1$ produces
$$
(((x\otimes a_1)\otimes a_2)\otimes a_3)...=2^{a_1} 3^{a_2} 5^{a_3} ...,
$$
from which the sequence $(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)$ is easily retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

The operations need to be specified, otherwise there is no solution.  Let me define a family of operations $f_z(x,y)=z$ (one for each real $z$, independent of $x, y$).  Clearly you cannot recover $x$ from the results of these operations.

Comment: I don't think the question is well posed.  Given that and $a_2=3$ there is no way to tell whether you applied $f_0(x,a_1)$ or $f_0(x,a_2)$ as the result is $0$ either way.  So you need to restrict what operations are allowable.  If the operations and $x$ are properly restricted you can find a set of $a$'s that let you identify which were used and what operation was done, but you can't leave it wide open.  For example, suppose we only allow addition and $0 \lt x \lt 2^{32}$.  Then if the $a_i$ are distinct powers of $2$ greater than $2^{3}1$ you can solve it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Ok lets suppose x = 1, a1 = 2, a2= 3, a3 = 5 etc i.e. all prime numbers. And the operation is multiplication i.e. x * a1 = 2 = y1. And y1 * a2 = 6 = y2. Now from y2, I can see that a1, a2 had performed the multiplication operation on it by dividing y2 with the given number and if the result is a whole number its a proof that y2 was resulted from the operation on x by that number. So, I dont need to have a set of operations. I just need one operation that can help me create this scenario to identify whether y is related to a.

Comment: So you are asking for an operation.  More than one only makes it harder.  If somebody else picks the $a$'s you can't guarantee that the results will be different.  As you say, if the $a$'s are all primes, multiplication works well (but watch out if $x$ matches one of the $a$'s).  My example of having the $a$'s powers of $2$ and the operation addition also works.  There are many other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be similar to [Gödel Numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering) and the more sophisticated [Gödel Numbering for Sequences.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering_for_sequences)